# How to interpret Foxpro syntax in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foxpro

I have a requirement where I need to convert Foxpro SQL syntax to SQL Server. What should be appropriate equivalent of below Foxpro code in SQL Server?

Here is complete statement:

Its a DBF Update statement in FoxPro:

```
REPLACE ALL Column1 WITH "N/A" FOR Column2="Some string value"=.f.
```

I want to understand what the `Column2="Some string value"=.f.` part means.

A per my assumption this code corresponds to below code in SQL Server:

```
columnName <> "String Value"
```

Please advise!

Comment: Rather than trying to translate, determine your requirements and see how the options in SQL Server help you meet those requirements. Cos those of us who know SQL Server but not Foxpro don't know what it should do, and those of us who know Foxpro but not SQL Server can't help.

Comment: You do understand how and why FoxPro is very, very, very different to SQL Server, right? While they both support "SQL", FoxPro is very much a 1980s-era dBase 4GL clone with rudimentary RDBMS functionality tacked-on, while SQL Server is _serious business_ in comparison - so from my position I think you have yet to appreciate the _sheer volume of work_ (and stress...) you've just signed-up for, because FoxPro/dBase is OLTP-one-record-at-a-time - modern RDBMS are all about set operations, not one-record-at-a-time.

Comment: actually I dont know foxpro and it is hard to understand what this statement is actually doing.

Comment: @DaleK Fortunately I know both - and I have the mental scars to prove it :3

Comment: @maddy_020 The single "statement" you've posted (`columnName="String Value"=.f.`) doesn't really tell us anything - you need to post more code, more context, and share more details of the system you're working on.

Comment: @Dai I have update the statement now to make it more clear.

Comment: @maddy_020 See this page: https://www.yaldex.com/fox_pro_tutorial/html/7f52db34-68fc-4f9e-abca-fa3f7f02ca19.htm

Comment: @Dai thanks for the link but I want to understand the statement I highlighted in bold in my post.

Comment: @maddy_020 That's not a statement, it's a clause and an expression.

Comment: Whow, hard to imagine there still is FoxPro code around. That stuff is ancient - likely older than most people here on the site. I would go back to whoever gave you the stuff and demand a: the documentation of the language and b: a runtime environment ;)

Comment: could you please help me understand this expression??

Comment: I am trying to, but you keep on interrupting me with new replies as I'm writing my answer...

Comment: When asking questions about VFP or Foxpro, try not adding other tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per the handy unofficial backup mirror of the FoxPro documentation](https://www.yaldex.com/fox_pro_tutorial/html/7f52db34-68fc-4f9e-abca-fa3f7f02ca19.htm), (because Microsoft has started to copy Apple's strategy of pretending documentation for their older products doesn't exist) we can break it down:

```
REPLACE ALL Column1 WITH "N/A" FOR Column2="Some string value"=.f.
```

- `REPLACE` is like SQL's `UPDATE` or `MERGE`.
- The `ALL` in `REPLACE ALL` means that all records in the table should be processed.
- `WITH "N/A"` means `"N/A"` is the new string/text value to store in `Column1`.
- `FOR` denotes the start of the row predicate (which seems silly as `ALL` is *also* a row predicate, kinda).
- `Column2 = "Some string value" = .f.` is the actual predicate expression.

  - [FoxPro has (at least) 2 comparison operators `=` and `==`](https://www.yaldex.com/fox_pro_tutorial/html/8935f327-b17d-4dcd-8f71-948f6b68a230.htm): the `==` operator is specifically for *exact* text equality, while `=` has looser rules for determining equivalence.
  - `.F.` (or `.f.`) is a literal `false` value, and `.T.` (or `.t.`) is a literal `true` value.
  - Annoyingly, the predicate is of the form `x = y = false` (rather than `( x = y ) = false` or `x = ( y = false )` - I couldn't find any authoritative documentation re: FoxPro's operator associativity, but from the context it's clear the intent is `( Column2 = "Some string value" ) = false` - which could have just been written as `FOR Column2 <> "Some string value"`.
- So this `REPLACE ALL` statement will:

  1. find all rows where `Column2` *is not equal to* `"Some string value"`
  2. and *only* in those rows will it set `Column1 = "N/A"`.
- The equivalent T-SQL for SQL Server would be:

  ```
  UPDATE
       tableNameGoesHere
  SET
       Column1 = 'N/A'
  WHERE
       Column2 <> N'Some string value';
  ```

  - Though keep-in-mind that SQL Server's `UPDATE` (and `MERGE`, if you dare) DML statements do have a lot more functionality than FoxPro had - for example, consider using the `OUTPUT` clause to return the actually changed data to the client or into a table without needing another `SELECT` - and `MERGE` lets you do `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` at the same time in a single statement ([with caveats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)) - so my point is that I think you should consider using this opportunity to explore how you can actively improve your product/project's codebase and functionality/features while you do this VFP-to-MSSQL porting work.

---

#### Update: Better docs

I found a copy of the Visual FoxPro documentation file (`.chm`) from the VFP9 CD and [I've uploaded it to the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dv_foxhelp) if anyone would like *unadulterated* VFP docs, as the unofficial mirror I linked to has clearly been (at least) aesthetically compromised...

It's here:https://archive.org/details/dv_foxhelp the `dv_foxhelp.chm` file should have a SHA-256 hash of `ABAA86E7623BB00E8BD9323CF2D8E162013598E35D9492557A3DDD1C2CF13E79`.

On Windows 10 you'll need to fiddle with CHM/IE settings otherwise it'll display only a white page:

- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1961503-solved-windows-10-chm-help-files-showing-up-blank
- https://www.helpsmith.com/chm-cannot-be-displayed.php

Comment: Whow. That is an archeological answer.

Comment: @TomTom I have an interest in these ooooold systems because it means I can see how systems/products/tools evolved over time, which makes me appreciate everything more (and I was really surprised to learn that SQL Server only added a `date` type in 2008! (The _really_ surprising thing is that I've been using SQL Server since 2000 (granted, in 2003) and I _could swear_ there was a `date` type back then, otherwise that would be like not having an `int` type - but no, I'm wrong - there _really was_ no `date` type in SQL Server for the first ~15 years of its existence...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"WTF - you took going somewhere and ChatGPT 4 - KNOWS THE FOXPRO SYNTAX. UPDATE YourTableName SET Column1 = 'N/A' WHERE Column2 = 'Some string value' Astonished. "_ - "going somewhere"? and what does ChatGPT have to with anything?

Comment: Given where you had to find it, I just asked ChatGPT in v4 to translate the statement from foxpro to sql server sql and - it knew the syntax. Just my surprise - given how old it is, I would not have expected it to have seen this documentation ;)

Comment: @TomTom Wanna be _really_ impressed? Ask ChatGPT to convert that FoxPro into Haskell. (And this is why GPT and LLM _emergent behaviour_ scares me, because I don't understand it, and I don't think any of us do...)

Comment: @Dai I have an instance of SQL Server 2005.  It does not have `DATE` type.

Comment: @Eric The weird thing is that I cannot remember _at all_ how on earth I stored date-only information back then... I was far too young at-the-time to have done something _sensible_ like using `datetime` with a `CHECK` constraint to ensure the time-of-day part was midnight - are there any examples in your 2005 instance?

Comment: Any of us? Dude, i read a research paper where the fact that AI work was attributed to "divine benevolence". I know how they work - from a program point. I know what they do. There is NO overlap between them. Completing sentences? SURE. Completing QUESTIONS like I ask them - NO EFFING WAY. Someone said that they get fed with random crap and the ONLY way to make sense of it is to become intelligent enough to interpret it, with their "intelligence" being basically a side effect of trying to make sense out of chaos.

Comment: @TomTom btw, I tried to access your website on your profile page but it gives me a cloudflare error

Comment: @Dai On submission from the web (eg: datepicker), it will be stored as '2022-01-02 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: @Dai Yep, server are still startiung up after months in storage ;) Need antoher week to get that stuff working again, I think...

Comment: You were very close.  Explanations are mostly right. SQL Statement has a very slim chance to be correct. BTW, don't trust to the documentation that you gave a link to. It doesn't seem to be correct at least for =, == operators.

Comment: Some of the FoxPro code I've seen plays fast and loose with which table is in context. The `REPLACE` command works on the table in context. That used to drive me nuts, because coders would deliberately select a different table and execute the same code. You had to pay really close attention to what was going on. If the OP's code is in a function, it could be _any_ table.

Comment: @StoneGiant, that is not entirely correct. REPLACE command, like many other commands, have a clause to specify the table it operates on. If you leave it off, then it operates on the table that is open in the current work area.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thank you for that clarification (and reminder). It has been a while since I worked with any of that stuff. The OP's command does not add the `IN` clause, so it will attempt to operate on the open table. Correct?

Comment: @StoneGiant, yes without IN clause it means current work area. You are right many developers use it deliberately and in a hard to trace way (you need to scroll up to see on which table it is operating on). Worse there could be function calls in between which change the work area (generally as a result of coding bug). Many developers use xBase commands less where they really beat SQL counterparts and prefer SQL instead.

Answer (score 3):

Dai made quite a good explanation and was *almost* right on what it does.

In SQL Server, **by default**, it would translate as (assuming the table name is theTable):

```
Update theTable 
set Column1 = 'N/A' 
where Column2 not like 'Some string value%';
```

That might also mean, but very unlikely:

```
Update theTable 
set Column1 = 'N/A' 
where Column2 <> 'Some string value';
```

The reason for this is in Foxpro by default, with xBase commands, the comparison is done up to the right operand's length.

EDIT: Also in VFP, the comparison is case sensitive. In SQL Server, it would likely be case-insensitive. That means:

Column2: 'some string value'

would be updated in VFP but not in SQL Server.

Taking that into account. In SQL Server, a more appropriate translation would be:

```
Update theTable 
set Column1 = 'N/A' 
where Column2 not like 'Some string value%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

EDIT: Here is some VFP code to show what it does (with default settings) - And BTW this is a very BAD use of VFP syntax:

```
Create Cursor crsSample (Id i, column1 c(10), column2 c(100))

Insert Into crsSample (Id, column2) Values (1, "Some string value")
Insert Into crsSample (Id, column2) Values (2, "some string value") && case sensitivity check
Insert Into crsSample (Id, column2) Values (3, "Some string value and some more")
Insert Into crsSample (Id, column2) Values (4, "some string value and some more") && case sensitivity check
Insert Into crsSample (Id, column2) Values (5, "Totally irrelevant")


Browse For column2="Some string value" Title [Column2="Some string value"]

Browse For column2="Some string value"=.F.  Title [Column2="Some string value"=.f.]
```

Comment: _"Also in VFP, the comparison is case sensitive"_ - I thought that was only when you use the `==` operator - if you use `=` it's a looser comparison (but I don't know exactly how it differs).

Comment: @Dai, no == has nothing to do with case sensitivity. VFP data is always case sensitive, you need to do lower(), or upper() on both sides for case insensitive comparison (or use a function that has case insensitive flag). == means roughly "exact match" but its behavior differs between xBase and SQL statements. With SQL trailing spaces are  ignored, xBase they are counted. (there are some more subtle differences not worth to mention - you can find them here or on foxite, I posted to both. Unfortunately I think here, the "documentation" or whatever it was called has gone)

Comment: Can you explain what the `=.f.` was for?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, it negates the check. IOW it means Column2 <> "Some string value", or (Column2 = "Some string value") = .F. or !(Column2 = "Some string value"). It is a very BAD use of VFP syntax IMHO.  I have seen worse code from amateurs. I will add some code to my reply to show it in VFP terms.